# How to summarize several filter-mutates in a case_when in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to calculate some quantiles for a variable, and capture to which quantile observations belong by creating a new variable. I manage to do every step individually and wonder how to combine them. I tried several `case_when` versions, none was working. How can I shorten the following:

```
paneldata = data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), time=seq(1:3), 
                       x=c(21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32))

quants <- boxplot(paneldata$x, outline=FALSE)$stats

library(dplyr)

paneldata %>%
  filter(x <= quants[2]) %>%
  mutate(quantile = 1)

paneldata %>%
  filter(x > quants[2] & x < quants[3]) %>%
  mutate(quantile = 2)

paneldata %>%
  filter(x > quants[3] & x < quants[4]) %>%
  mutate(quantile = 3)

paneldata %>%
  filter(x >= quants[4]) %>%
  mutate(quantile = 4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it all in a single step with `ntile()` from `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

paneldata %>%
  mutate(quantile = ntile(x, 4))

   id time  x  quantile
1   1    1 21         1
2   1    2 22         1
3   1    3 23         1
4   2    1 24         2
5   2    2 25         2
6   2    3 26         2
7   3    1 27         3
8   3    2 28         3
9   3    3 29         3
10  4    1 30         4
11  4    2 31         4
12  4    3 32         4
```